# How to read multiple values from a single line of input in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on a java program and I want to allow a user to enter multiple values in a single line.

it likes :

```
setting something in location X and y Eg.. :s x y 
Enter next action: S 2 1
```

the s is like like setting , adding ......

and the 2 1 is the location X and Y.

I cannot post my source code, but I wanted to know if this is possible. thanks

Comment: You should create a minimal and reproducible example of code if you cannot post your source code.   There you could clearly explain what you have tried and what you have not.  
Why not read the entire input as a string and split the string using ws as delimiter?

`String[] inputs = totalInputAsString.split(' ',3)`

Comment: Your question is really unclear and poorly formatted.

Comment: Seems pretty clear.  "I want to allow user to enter multiple values in a single line"
With S 2 1 as example input.

Answer (score 1):

Read input as a string and split.

```
String inputs = "s 2 1";
String[] splitInput = inputs.split(" ",3);
```